# React.js – filter multiple indexOf

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im just looking for a bit of advice regarding React.js filtering. I am currently filtering ‘peopleList’ by ‘employeeName’ and this is working fine, im getting back exactly what I expect.

But I wanted to also filter by the ‘employeeID’ at the same time i.e. check if ‘employeeName’ or ‘employeeID’ contain an indexOf..  Is this possible or would I need to set up two filters for 'employeeName’ and 'employeeID’?

```
let people= this.state.peopleList.filter(
        (person) => {
            return person.record.employeeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            // return person.record.employeeID.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried using `||`, the *or* operator? `employeeNameIndexOf !== -1 || employeeIdIndexOf !== -1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your condition is either one OR the other, you can use the `||` operator

```
const { search, peopleList } = this.state
const searchStr = search.toLowerCase()

const people = peopleList.filter((person) =>
  person.record.employeeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr) !== -1 ||
  person.record.employeeId.indexOf(searchStr) !== -1
)
```

Comment: Thank you. this worked great!! I was trying to do this but I didn’t have it structured properly.